# Expect does not detect string

Tags: shell, expect

I need to automate the input of a string in a command called from a shell (sh) script, using `expect` To accomplish this I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
MY_ARGS="-a -b -c" expect -c "
      spawn mycommand $MY_ARGS
      expect 'continue, I know what I am doing' { send -- 'continue, I know what I am doing\r' }
      expect eof"
```

The `mycommand` output is:

```
Enter "continue, I know what I am doing" to use the outdated data anyway:
```

But the string is not being detected and therefore nothing is sent. What is wrong with the expect command?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the output or the error you got pls?

Comment: single quotes are not special in Tcl/Expect. use double quotes instead.

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here:

- When you write `var=value some_command`, then `$var` is set in the *environment* for the command.
  Inside expect you need `$env(MY_ARGS)`
- But now you have a quoting problem, you can't put the expect body in double quotes because you
  don't want the shell to expand that variable.
- @sexpect_Expect.for.Shells is right, single quotes are not special in Tcl (and hence expect). expect sees this:

  ```
    expect {
      {'continue,} {I}
      {know}       {what}
      {I}          {am}
      {doing'}     { send -- "'continue," "I" "know" "what" "I" "am" "doing\r'" }
    }
  ```

To solve the quoting problems, I recommand using a quoted heredoc in the shell

```
export MY_ARGS='-a -b -c' 
# .......v..........v  these quotes are crucial
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    set phrase "continue, I know what I am doing"
    set timeout -1
    spawn mycommand {*}$env(MY_ARGS)
    expect $phrase
    send -- "$phrase\r"
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```

Note how I expanded the env variable: `{*}$env(MY_ARGS)` -- the [`{*}` syntax](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9) splits the variable content into separate words.